# stacked bar chart in ggplot when converted to plotly doesnt render right

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly, stacked-chart

update: adding a minimum reproducible code for the data.

im trying to convert a ggplot to plotly chart in shiny. The problem is that in ggplot, the stacked bar chart (with stat =identity) stacks up nicely without any spaces in between, whereas when i convert to plotly, there are these spaces in between each item.

I am not producing the entire code for shiny, as it is difficult to follow. However here are the images and a much simplified code (not the shiny version)

```
t<- 1:50
GIB_Rating = rep(c('2','3','4+','5','5-','7','8','6','6+','5'),5)
t1<-data.frame(t,GIB_Rating)
CapitalChargeType = c('Credit_risk_Capital','NameConcentration','SectorConcentration')
t2<- expand.grid(t=t, CapitalChargeType=CapitalChargeType)
t3<-left_join(t2,t1)
New = rnorm(150, mean=100,sd=250)
t3<- data.frame(t3,New)

t3<- ggplot(t3, aes(x=GIB_Rating, y=New, fill=CapitalChargeType)) + geom_bar(stat='identity') 
t3
```

this produces this image some what like this, which is exactly what I want. 
[image]

However as it is not interactive, I want a plotly image, which shows the total of capital charge type when cursor hovers over. so, I use the code below

```
t4<-ggplotly(t3)
t4
```

the plotly plot now produced has white lines (for each individual item) in between each color class (Capitalchargetype), which i want to avoid, also the tooltip also produces individual items rather than the sum of each CapitalChargeType 
[image]

Comment: can you provide a reproducible example of your data?

Comment: Done now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is in the way plotly handles stacked bars of factors. Each factor gets wrapped in a border which is white by default. There's a very easy workaround: Just add `color = CapitalChargeType` to the ggplot object.

```
library(tidyverse)
df <- data_frame(
  t = 1:50,
  GIB_Rating = rep(c('2','3','4+','5','5-','7','8','6','6+','5'),5)
)

df <- df %>%
  expand(t, CapitalChargeType = 
c('Credit_risk_Capital','NameConcentration','SectorConcentration')) %>%
  left_join(df) %>%
  mutate(New = rnorm(150, mean=100,sd=250))

g <- ggplot(df, aes(x = GIB_Rating, y = New, fill = CapitalChargeType, color = CapitalChargeType)) + 
  geom_bar(stat='identity') 

plotly::ggplotly(g)
```

[image: plotly output]

Comment: This works, however, the tooltip still shows individual values rather than the sum of each CapitalChargeType. I realise one way to fix this is to change the data and plot the computed group sums , but is there a plotting feature that I am missing, by which i can make the tooltip show sums ? And thanks for showing me a nicer way to create the min reproducible example.